# FFT for Fourier Integrals of analytic Functions

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

So, I'm trying to implement a fourier-transform of an analytic function through DFT or FFT as I'm only interested in a certain frequency range. So far I've tested Numerical Recipes' FFT algorithm "four1" of "fourier.h" for an analytic function, i.e. a Lorentzian'
 
`f(t) = 1.0 / (1.0 + t*t)`
 which transforms analytically into
 
`f(w) = sqrt(Pi/2) * Exp[-Abs[w]]`.
 
So far so good, the FFT routine now takes an array of input data of complex & real values respectively. My idea was, that I just sample my function `f(t)` for a fixed Range, say `[-12,12]` in steps of 1, and then give a data array with these as Real-values and the Imaginary values set to 0, to the NR routine four1, and obtain the Real and Imaginary arrays. 
My problem now is, that I can't seem to reproduce the analytical `f(w)` when giving an array data[0...2*n] of the sampled `f(t)` to four1. There seems to be an offset included in all datapoints I get back. The array containing the Real-valued data i get back doesn't seem to follow the expected `Exp[-Abs[w]]` dependency when plotted either. Has anybody experienced a similar problem or knows how to make the `four1` routine behave?

Comment: You can't expect to get the same spectrum when sampling the continuous function and discarding all data points except for a small range. Have you tried to use Matlab or similar tools to exclude any programmatic errors?

Comment: I've also tried the FFTW library, which apparently gives the same results.Matlab also uses FFTW if I recall correctly. So..to get an approximation of the analytic spectrum a much bigger and narrower range of data is required?

Comment: I think your biggest concern is [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). You have a signal that has content at all frequencies, and by sampling this signal you alias frequencies higher than half the sampling rate to the "base band". This is probably why you get an offset in the resulting fft compared to the desired signal.

Comment: This might indeed be the problem. Thanks for you help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!